# Get current memory usage of a tmux session

Tags: shell, memory, tmux, session, cpu-usage

I need a way to the used memory of a current tmux session. I am not sure if that is even possible. I am using tmux to start multiple minecraft servers I'd like to know each servers memory usage.

Comment: tmux and minecraft are separate programs, and will have different memory usage.  You can get (an upper bound) of their memory use with `ps` (as well as various system-specific tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to run `pgrep server_binary` to know the `PID` of each instance and then `top -p PIDs` to know all `virtual memory`, `resident memory` and `shared memory` used by each bash instance.

**Example**

```
#know PID of each bash instance
> pgrep bash
4301
4420
4426
4432
4438
4444
4450
4456

#list all resources used by each instance
> top -p 4301,4420,4426,4432,4438,4444,4450,4456
```

[image: top example]